# Linux Bash Script String Equality Problem

Tags: linux, string, bash

I tried to run bash script which is like that :

```
#!/bin/bash

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=X   ## censored
export PATH=$PATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

CONNECTION='X'  ##  censored
echo $CONNECTION
RETVAL=`sqlplus -silent $CONNECTION <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 50 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
SELECT 'Alive' FROM dual;
EXIT;
EOF`

echo $RETVAL


if [ "$RETVAL" = "Alive" ];
then
    echo 'Database is running.'
    exit 1
else
    echo 'Database is NOT running.'
fi


exit
```

When I run this sh result is like that :

```
sh checkdbstatus.sh 

X
Alive
Database is NOT Running.
```

Why result is not  Database is running ?

$RETVAL and Alive are equal ? And I am sure db is running.

Thank you

I expect to see result is Database is running.

Comment: Check the output or rather replace `echo ...` with `printf '<%s>\n' "$RETVAL"` there might be some invisible spaces/blanks. On a side note `1` is considered a failure in shell scripts. See `help exit` and  `man 1p exit`

Comment: Could you please try to parse the script with shellcheck.net. This will already point to various issues. From there, I believe we can help you further

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` and it'll log what it's doing, so you can see _why_ it doesn't see the values as equal.

Comment: Why are you exiting non-zero when the database is running, and zero when it is not?  That seems backward.  If the db is not running, I would expect the script to fail.  (return non-zero)

Comment: BTW, `sh yourscript` runs your script with `sh`, completely ignoring the `#!/bin/bash` on the first line. `sh` is not `bash`. If you have a _bash_ script, it should be run as `bash yourscript`. (This confusion is part of why naming shell scripts with .sh extensions is a bad idea; see a larger essay on the topic at https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 0):

I mean, i had read string testing should be done like this (at least with Busybox sh):

if [[ "$RETVAL" == "Alive" ]];

I looked trough some of my own scripts, and since 3 Years i use double brackets "[[" and double equalsigns "=="
I'll also remember i had a problem with invisible char (was some ansi-escape code) in output of an command. I found that by piping the command output to a textfile..

Answer (score -1):

The `sqlplus` command probably adds an invisible newline character to `$RETVAL`.

Try this:

`if [[ "$RETVAL" =~ ^Alive ]];`

Comment: Any trailing newline is removed by the shell during command substitution. I agree that this probably _does_ involve hidden characters, but it wouldn't be caused by a newline, and could just as easily be caused by leading whitespace instead.